# how to train a bot's intent for a user phrase not known?

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es

I have to train my dialogflow bot with a phrase i dont know i.e user can type anything he or she wants but i want that to work with a single intent only.
for example:

```
U- Good Morning 
B- Morning how can i help you?
U- i want to create a ticket 
B- Please provide a subject for the issue?
U- No i want to view a ticket with id ABC1234556
```

Now here bot should back track to another intent which will view the details related to the ticket id but thats not happening i am using dialogflow's system entity i.e @sys.any which captures anything user says. This entity captures anything and even back tracks on other intent's phrases like bye show all ticket's and etc but it just not works with this particular intent phrase!

I hope i have made clear what is bothering!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using @sys.any in an intent to capture all user input after asking `Please provide a subject for the issue`, it won't be possible for another intent to be matched within Dialogflow.

To get around this issue, you could change your agent design, perhaps by confirming the "subject" in case the user wants to change path.

You could also try and match an intent to whatever text is captured by @sys.any, by calling Dialogflow's [detectIntent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent) endpoint from your webhook. However, this might result in unwanted behavior (e.g. if a legitimate ticket subject happened to match one of your intents).